# Отсортировать combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

Возможно ли отсортировать `combobox`, если присвоена ссылка на коллекцию?

```
combobox1.DataSource = list;
```

Comment: А почему нельзя отсортировать до присвоения к DataSource?

Comment: Сделал вот так var result = listOfWeapon.OrderBy(point => point.Name).ToList();
            comboBoxOfWeapon.DataSource = result; Вроде работает, но если имена начинается с одного слова, сортировка не происходит. Убрал пробелы, все равно не сортирует.

Comment: У списка есть свой метод сортировки `List.Sort`.